# Display number of leap years between two years in a single dialog box

Tags: java

I need a little help. I kind of want my output to show a tabled format of the leap years.

But even though my program does work... it doesn't necessarily come up like the one in the picture. Can anyone show me how to work it?

Here's my input:
**2000 - 2020**

Here's my output (but in separate JOptionPane popup boxes):
**2000**, **2004**, **2008**, **2012**, **2016**

Here's my code:

```
    String enterYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the starting year: \nExample: 2015");   // User enters an input (Year)
    String enterLastYear = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the ending year: ");
    int i = Integer.parseInt(enterYear);
    int x = Integer.parseInt(enterLastYear);
    String output = "";

    if (i < x){
        for (i = Integer.parseInt(enterYear); i < x; i ++ ){
            if(i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0) {

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i + "");
            }
        }
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: Starting Year is greater than Ending Year!");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does your popup look different than the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you show a popup for each result since you call the `showMessageDialog` in each run of the `for` loop.

Change your code so that a result string with all the "answers" is created in the loop, then show the result dialog once.

Also, you already parsed the `int` value and assigned it to `i` before the loop, so dont't do it twice and leave it out of your loop header.

```
if (i < x){
    //we use this variable to count the number of leap years that we already found
    int noOfResults = 0;
    String results = "";
    for (; i < x; i ++ ){ //i loops over the years
        //i is a leap year when this expression is true:
        if(i % 4 == 0 && i % 100 != 0 || i % 400 == 0) {
            //add the leap year to the result string:
            results += i + " ";
            //increase the number of found results by 1:
            noOfResults++;
            //for every 5th result, we add a line break to the result string
            // this is done with the % sign, the modulo operator
            // which returns the remainder of a division
            // meaning that everytime we loop through this, it is
            // checked if the remainder of noOfResults divided by 5 is zero
            if(noOfResults % 5 == 0){
                results += "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, results);
}
```

Comment: Oh, I totally forgot about the range of scope for for-loop statements! The output came out correctly, but the format didn't. Any hints on how the code so the output comes out like the one shown in the picture (above)?

Comment: Well what exactly do you want? Your screenshot shows the values being seperated by spaces, which is what's happening here.

Comment: Kind of like this image here: http://oi57.tinypic.com/5behxd.jpg

My output shows a LONG line of years (horizontally)

Comment: Okay, sounds like you need manual linebreaks in the result string. The screenshot shows a linebreak after each 5 results, I'll update the code.

Comment: I'm still new to JAVA, so could you explain how this line of code works to me? I want to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this line inside your loop

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, i + "");
```

concatenate the variable `i` and a space (`" "`) to the end of your String output.
Then do the `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` outside your loop, but inside your `if`.
You may need to add code to keep track of how many values are in your string and add a `\n` if that number is divisible by 4 or whatever number your choose.